# Windows Mixed Reality for non-admin user doesn’t show anything

Tags: windows-10, virtual-reality

So I’ve found that Windows Mixed Reality works happily on my PC.

However, if another, non-admin user tries to run it under their account - everything sets up, but when it switches to the headset - they can only see their controllers: No game or environment shows up. So they are stuck in a black space with only their controllers.

I can see the game happening if I mirror to the desktop, but the user can’t see that video in their headset.

I’m assuming its a permissions thing? Since everything works fine for the admin user on the machine.